# net 5 web api in docker with https

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, .net-5

I followed this https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md
to get my net 5 web api application working in docker with Https. When I execute the run command  :
`docker run --rm -it -p 8080:80 -p 8081:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8081 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -v ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets -v ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/ weatherapi`
everything works fine. I tried moving it to a docker compose file as shown below:

```
 version: '3.8'
services:
  weatherapi:
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8081:443'
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT="8081"
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
    volumes: 
      - ${HOME}/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/
```

then I get this error even though am running the same command as the one above:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
weatherapi_1  |       Unable to start Kestrel.
weatherapi_1  |       System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
weatherapi_1  |       To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
weatherapi_1  |       For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
weatherapi_1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
weatherapi_1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
weatherapi_1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
weatherapi_1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
weatherapi_1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
weatherapi_1  |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
weatherapi_1  | Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
```

Inspecting the container created by the first command I could see the environment variable and volumes paths is different to that of the container created by the docker-compose:

From command container:

```
 "HostConfig": {
                "Binds": [
                    "/Users/xxxx/.microsoft/usersecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets",
                    "/Users/xxxx/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https/"
},
"Env": [
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+",
                "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8081",
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
                "DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.0",
                "ASPNET_VERSION=5.0.0"
            ]
```

From docker-compose container:

```
"HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/Users/xxxx/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:rw",
            "/Users/xxxx/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:rw"
        ]
}
"Env": [
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+",
            "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=\"8081\"",
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=\"Development\"",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
            "DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.0",
            "ASPNET_VERSION=5.0.0"
        ]
```

I spotted the difference in the url to user secrets: /usersecrets/:/root/ vs /usersecrets:/root.

I can't get my app to start in the container with the same dev certificate the command is using despite the docker-compose file is exactly the same thing as the command and indicating the volumes and paths.

Comment: Don't enquote the docker compose environment variable values.

Comment: @DanielFarrell that worked! I can't believe it was just because of that.

Comment: I could tell because the environment values shown from docker compose showed the quotes, which made it obvious that they weren't being parsed as expected from the docker-compose file.